# Warning reported on variable assigned, but not used when it is used

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

VSCode is reporting a warning that a variable is assigned but never used. Execution of the code makes it appear that the variable is used. Why is it reporting a warning/error?

```
The variable 'x' is assigned but never used.PSScriptAnalyzer(PSUseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments)
```

Given the code:

```
$x = 2
@(1,2,3) | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
    switch ($_) {
        0 {
            Write-Host 'it is 0'
        }
        1 {
            Write-Host 'it is 1'
            $x = 7    # WARNING ON THIS LINE
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $x
```

Result of execution

```
PS C:\src\sql\validate> .\scopetest.ps1
1
it is 1
2
3
7
PS C:\src\sql\validate> code --version
1.62.1
f4af3cbf5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f
x64
PS C:\src\sql\validate> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.0
```

Comment: It's probably a scoping issue. It's not used *within the `foreach-object` block*.

Comment: I found it. I can reference it with script scope as $script.x`. Is that better than disabling the message?

Comment: @lit it's not better or worse; but it's a different thing, with different behavior, so I don't recommend you do that to get around a linting error. Within a script itself, `$Script:` scope is kinda like making it a global variable (the `$Global:` scope is even more wide-ranging actually), so if your real code is not all flat in the script, and is functions for example, you're breaking out of the function scope. You might introduce real errors that way. Adding the attribute to disable the message like in the linked duplicate does not change the code behavior.